# Is Authorization code mandatory to grant resource access?

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a Spring Boot web app that needs to access the resource from 3rd party web app. I am trying to understand the working of Oauth2. The 3rd party web app uses Oauth2 to grant the client resource access. The document from 3rd party web app says to send a POST with request parameter in the below-mentioned format.

username=<###>&password=<###>&client_id=<###>&client_secret=<###>&grant_type=password&hcode=<###>

The hcode value is fixed as per the document.
I am able to write a java code that successfully fetches me access token (thanks to Google search!).
Below are my questions...

1. What type of grant is being used here?
2. Is this Authorization code grant? I don't see Authorization code here.

PS: I am new to web application development. I am referring to the below post to understand Oauth2.
[https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-oauth-introduction]

```
String content = "-----";
BufferedReader reader = null;
HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
String returnValue = "";

URL url = new URL(CredentialDto.getTockenurl());
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + 
CredentialDto.getAuthentication());
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
PrintStream os = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());

os.print(content);

os.close();
reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line = null;

StringWriter out = new StringWriter(connection.getContentLength() > 0 ? 
connection.getContentLength() : 2048);

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
        }

accessToken = out.toString();       
Matcher matcher = PAT.matcher(retuenValue); if(matcher.matches() && 
matcher.groupCount() > 0) { 
              accessToken = matcher.group(1); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1   What type of grant is being used here?

Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC). Check this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)

2   Is this Authorization code grant? I don't see Authorization code here.

NO.

Comment: thanks for the response. The parameter has hcode which is a code related to the resource (clinic code in this case) . Why is this being asked during access token get stage? After getting the token I am retrievint patient details.

Comment: I kind of understood why clientID, clientSecret, userID and userPassword is sent in parameter. I am not clear on why grantType and hcode being sent.

Comment: There are multiple grant types (implicit, Authorization Code, Client Credentials etc and ROPC in your case) available in OAuth. So you need to specify, which grant type you are using, so resource server can initiate that flow. hcode is not a standard OAuth parameter, could be something specific to Clinic Code.